# How to fix my local administrator?

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator, privileges, user-groups

Starting a few days ago, I am facing a very weird issue here on my Windows 8.1 workstation. I am unable to start programs or applications that require administrator privileges. This makes my PC completely unusable at the moment, because I cannot even run "taskmgr.exe" or edit user profiles (which is the reason, I am asking). The only thing working are "usual" programs, like my browser.

What happens whenever I am trying to start a program as administrator is, that there's a horribly long timeout where nothing happens, followed by the message quoted below:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\system32\taskmgr.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

I found many sites suggesting many things... things like:

> `sfc /scannow`
>
> `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
>
> `runas /user:Administrator /profile "cmd.exe"`

or enabling the built-in administrator

> `net /user:administrator /active:yes`

However, all of these approaches are requesting administrator privileges and thus are not working.

Is there any way, I can try to fix this problem without reinstalling Windows (which appears to be my last option at the moment...)?

Comment: Can you run system restore?

Comment: @Wutnaut: I tried this too, but my boot image is somehow not recognized as such. I keep trying this anyway... any other hints would be nice!

Comment: Can *you* find C:\Windows\system32\tasmgr.exe?

Comment: Is this your personal computer, or a company resource? If the latter, go with the coffee & donuts solution suggested by @YetiFiasco. If the former, it's probably time for a rebuild anyway. Some *very* restrictive UAC configurations can prevent you from being able to run commands that require elevation without already being in an elevated session (e.g.: use an elevated CMD prompt instead of Start->Run), but you usually won't see that at home.

Comment: When you ran those commands.  What error exactly did you receive?  Update your question to include it.

Comment: @Izam: Yes. @Iszi: It's my personal computer. Funny thing is: it's a 3 months old setup! @Ramhound: The error is always the same (the commands result in various forms of "unauthorized" errors since I am unable to start `cmd` as admin...)

Comment: Do you have access to an Admin-level account? Or is someone else responsible for administering the system?

Comment: @Iszi: Yes, my local account is an administrator account. Another one does not exist (except the built-in admin, which I cannot activate, because I do not have admin privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this to work without reinstalling or refreshing windows!

I restarted the PC (by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking *Restart*) and switched to safe mode using *Advanced Options*. From here I was able to run (at least) my console as administrator. This enabled me to run `sfc /scannow` which told me that there was indeed an error that will be fixed after reboot.

And it did!